# regex ?: performance

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the difference between this regex: `/(everything|cool)/gi` and this one: `/(?:everything|cool)/gi` ?

I'm asking this because I've got an regex which *I wasn't able to write myself** and there are, as you can see below, a lot of `?:` in that regex. I've read somewhere that `?:` is bad for performance so I want to remove it.Can I remove it or is it important for anything?

* `(?:(?=(?:(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'"])*'(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"'\\])*"|[^\\'])*')*(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'])*$)(?=(?:(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\'"])*"(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'"\\])*'|[^\\"])*")*(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\"])*$)(?:\\.|[^\\'"]))+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `?:`, a reference to a matched group is created.
With a `?:`, the group is matched, but not captured.

Here's a benchmark on both methods: http://jsperf.com/regex-capture-vs-non-capture

By looking at the bars, one would say that the non-captured groups are faster. However, if you look at the bottom, the differences can be neglected, since both methods are already incredibly fast.

Removing or adding `?:` to an existing solution might break the code, so I advise to not edit the RegExp when it's not causing any issues.

Answer (score 4):

`(?:...)` is fine.  It's when *capturing* groups, and particularly backreferences to them, get involved that you start seeing performance hits.

Comment: The key to why non-capturing groups are faster is that they allow the RE engine to do a lot of optimization. Capturing groups require a lot more information to be kept by the matcher, and that defeats a lot of the more complex optimizations (such as conversion to a single-pass DFA).

Comment: Oddly, i see better performance with a non-capturing group than even with no group at all.  :P  http://jsperf.com/regex-capture-vs-non-capture/2  (Probably v8 specific)

Comment: That's a really curious result. I wonder if there were any issues with garbage collection kicking in? (I suspected that's what happened when I ran the test on that page…)

Comment: @micha: `exec` has its place.  IIRC it returns all the matches -- and it's probably the most effective way of doing so.  (At the very least, it's the simplest.)  But if you only care whether there's a match in the string (and not where it is, or what exactly matched), `test` is the better choice.

Comment: @cHao but I've got `RegExp.$1` and so on for that after calling `test` too.

Comment: @micha: `$1` thru `$9` are apparently deprecated.  You shouldn't really be using them if you care about your scripts working in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You should have heard that `(foo)` is slower than `(?:foo)`. This is because the first one is a *capturing group*, and the second one is a *non-capturing group*. the second one has less work to do (it doesn't need to remember the text that matched), so it should be faster.